# How to remove children background color from ExpansionTile title on animation?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code:

```
class Temp extends StatefulWidget {
  const Temp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Temp> createState() => _TempState();
}

// stores ExpansionPanel state information
class Item {
  Item(bool exp) {
    this.isExpanded = exp;
  }
  late bool isExpanded;
}

List<Item> items = [Item(false), Item(true), Item(true), Item(false)];

class _TempState extends State<Temp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              child: ExpansionPanelList(
                expandedHeaderPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
                  setState(() {
                    items[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
                  });
                },
                children: [
                  ExpansionPanel(
                    headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text("Test", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
                        leading: Icon(Icons.info),
                        minLeadingWidth : 4,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                        dense:true,
                      );
                    },
                    body: Column(
                      children: [
                          ListTile(
                          title: Text("Test 1", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                          leading: Icon(Icons.handshake_outlined),
                          minLeadingWidth : 4,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                          dense:true,
                        ),
                        ExpansionTile(
                          title: const Text('Test 2', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),),
                          leading: Icon(Icons.handshake_outlined, color: Colors.black54,),
                          trailing: Column(),
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ListTile(
                              dense: true,
                              tileColor: Color(0xffffeed4),
                              title: Text('Foo', style: TextStyle (fontSize: 16),),
                              trailing: SizedBox(
                                  child: Text("foo", style: TextStyle (fontSize: 16),)
                              ),
                            ),
                            ListTile(
                              tileColor: Color(0xffffeed4),
                              title: Text('Bar', style: TextStyle (fontSize: 16),),
                              dense: true,
                              trailing: SizedBox(
                                  child: Text("bar", style: TextStyle (fontSize: 16),)
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 10,
                              color: Color(0xffffeed4),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              color: Color(0xffffeed4),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  TextButton(
                                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
                                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                                    ),
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.copy,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                  ),
                                  TextButton(
                                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
                                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                                    ),
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.delete_rounded,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                  ),
                                  TextButton(
                                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
                                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                                    ),
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.info_outline,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 10,
                              color: Color(0xffffeed4),
                            )

                          ],
                          onExpansionChanged: (bool expanded) {
                            //setState(() => _customTileExpanded = expanded);
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    isExpanded: items[1].isExpanded,
                    canTapOnHeader: true
                  ),
                ],

              ),
            ),
          ),

          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: null,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        )
    );

  }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

As you see when I click on `ExpansionTile` title/header then children background is visible not only on this `ExpansionTile` title/header (`Test 2`) but also on the previous one (`Test 1`). As a result it is rather ugly. I don't want children background color be visible on `ExpansionTile` title/header. Could anyone say how to do it?

Comment: Can you include full widget

Comment: Possible, I need to check the source code, it might not be using clipping property

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in flutter. Issue is [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107030)